# X-editable date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I have the following JS and HTML for a X-editable date field. After I pick a date from the calendar popup, I will see "Wed Apr 13 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)" as the new value in my input box. And It's not in the format "mm/dd/yyyy" that I have specified already.

```
<input style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" 
   title="" 
   data-original-title="" 
   class="editable editable-click dateinput form-control" 
   data-clear="false" 
   data-format="mm/dd/yyyy" 
   data-type="date" 
   id="my_date" 
   name="my_date" 
   required="required" 
   value="12/31/2016" 
   type="text">

<script>     
$("#my_date").editable({
             send: 'never',
             success: function(response, newValue) {
                    $('#my_date').val(newValue);
             }
});       
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this.Put a `date format` within the `js` file as shown below.

```
<script>     
$("#my_date").editable({
             format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',    
             send: 'never',
             success: function(response, newValue) {
                    $('#my_date').val(newValue);
             }
});       
</script>
```